# HMS IAP API returned “paymentToken siteID invalid” when verifying purchase token

Tags: in-app-purchase, huawei-mobile-services

I am integrating HMS IAP with my own server, I tested a subscription purchase and initiated my server to call IAP server API ({rootUrl}/applications/purchases/tokens/verify) to verify the purchase token but I received this message:

`{"responseCode":"6","responseMessage":"paymentToken siteID invalid"}`

What is "paymentToken siteID invalid"? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

The IAP server API that you used is for verifying the purchase token for the non-subscription order services. That is why you receive that message.

You should use subscription service API instead `- {rootUrl}/sub/applications/v2/purchases/get`

You can read more about the api documents [here](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-References-V5/api-subscription-verify-purchase-token-0000001050706080-V5).

Here is an example:

```
POST /sub/applications/v2/purchases/get
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Authorization: Basic QVQ6Q1YzQ1NPbVlBaGwrZUtRWExtMTBVV2pyWXZHTVF4MmYvcVMya1B0ZElLY3UwaFJrdFNTMmxwdk1FQkIyYldXWGt0REVaR3I4UjFUTTRLMVlmNXdwWU80RG04THdXQWxjaFhEYjBMUjBNTUJtWnFYcGFtazc3THN3UnFJbkhHK28xekdqRzNSMg==
Accept: application/json
Content-Length: 171
{
  "purchaseToken": "00000173741056a37eef310dff9c6a86fec57efafe318ae478e52d9c4261994d64c8f6fc8ea1abbdx5347.5.3089",
  "subscriptionId": "1581789719266.D40972AC.3089"
}
```

Please also refer to this document - [Verifying the Purchase Token for the Subscription Service](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides-V5/subscription-verify-purchase-token-0000001050035029-V5)

Comment: Ok, thanks for pointing out the right document, I've made a mistake.